# uwsgi-emperor refuses to accept concurrent requests despite monkeypatch in flask-socketio with gevent

Tags: uwsgi, gevent, flask-socketio, monkeypatching

I'm using flask-socketio along with uwsgi emperor.

In the SocketIO config, I employ "gevent_uwsgi" as my async_handler.

When I attempt to connect to the server, the connection is successfully established. However, any additional requests get blocked until I close this connection first. Hence, no concurrency.

I reviewed the docs and employed the gevent monkey patching but to no avail.

I also used the gevent-monkey-patch tag in my uwsgi config.

Monkey patch:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

SocketIO configuration:

```
    socketio = SocketIO(
        app,
        cors_allowed_origins="*",
        async_mode="gevent_uwsgi",
        async_handlers = True,
        message_queue = "redis://",
        logger=True,
        engineio_logger=True
    )
```

uwsgi configuration:

```
    [uwsgi]
    plugin-dir=/usr/local/lib/uwsgi
    plugins=python27
    uwsgi-socket = :5000
    #processes = 2
    gevent = 1000
    gevent-monkey-patch = true
    http-websockets = true
    enable-threads = true
    master = true
    wsgi-file = run.py
    callable = app
    virtualenv = /path/to/virtualenv
    chdir = /srv/app
    socket = /tmp/uwsgi.app.socket
    uid = www-data
    gid = www-data
    chmod-socket = 666
    #logto2 = /tmp/uwsgi
```

Log Output on Closing the Socket Connection:

```
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Sending packet OPEN data {'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'upgrades': [], 'sid': '3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591'}
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Received request to upgrade to websocket
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Upgrade to websocket successful
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/messageinstancepage,
emitting event "my_response" to 3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591 [/messageinstancepage]
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0/messageinstancepage
3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/messageinstancepage,["my_response",{"data":"Connected","result":true}]
emitting event "my_response" to 3501033f36ad4a519a861419d1c66591 [/messageinstancepage]
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 26/26] 197.239.12.61 () {40 vars in 564 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:22 2023] GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket => generated 205 bytes in 2491 msecs (HTTP/1.1 101) 4 headers in 188 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
ca6f2ee7284c4b2bad567944dc66bfd2: Sending packet OPEN data {'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'upgrades': [], 'sid': 'ca6f2ee7284c4b2bad567944dc66bfd2'}
ca6f2ee7284c4b2bad567944dc66bfd2: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
ca6f2ee7284c4b2bad567944dc66bfd2: Received request to upgrade to websocket
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket (ip 197.239.12.61) !!!
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 238] during GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket (197.239.12.61)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 44, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 59, in __call__
    return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 360, in handle_request
    return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 273, in handle_request
    transport, b64)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 392, in _handle_connect
    ret = s.handle_get_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 103, in handle_get_request
    start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 145, in _upgrade_websocket
    return ws(environ, start_response)
  File "/srv/aucbooks/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/async_gevent_uwsgi.py", line 35, in __call__
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake()
IOError: unable to complete websocket handshake
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 27/27] 197.239.12.61 () {40 vars in 564 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023] GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket => generated 0 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 101) 4 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /api/v2/bookdata (ip 197.239.12.61) !!!
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/v2/bookdata (197.239.12.61)
IOError: write error
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 28/28] 197.239.12.61 () {54 vars in 745 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023] POST /api/v2/bookdata => generated 0 bytes in 213 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /api/v2/bookfollows (ip 197.239.14.61) !!!
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/v2/bookfollows (197.239.14.61)
IOError: write error
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 29/29] 197.239.14.61 () {54 vars in 751 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023] POST /api/v2/bookfollows => generated 0 bytes in 274 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /api/v2/bookdata (ip 197.239.14.61) !!!
Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/v2/bookdata (197.239.14.61)
IOError: write error
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 30/30] 197.239.14.61 () {54 vars in 745 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023] POST /api/v2/bookdata => generated 0 bytes in 66 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Thu Jul 20 11:09:26 2023 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /api/v1/librarybooks (ip 197.239.12.61) !!!
Thu Jul 20 11:09:26 2023 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/v1/librarybooks (197.239.12.61)
IOError: write error
[pid: 22179|app: 0|req: 31/31] 197.239.12.61 () {54 vars in 753 bytes} [Thu Jul 20 11:09:25 2023] POST /api/v1/librarybooks => generated 0 bytes in 371 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Please help!